# ¿Porqué el position sticky no funciona cuando esta en múltiples contenedores?

Tags: html, css, sticky

He buscado y analizado la respuesta que se tienen sobre este tema, pero realmente no me queda claro cual es la solución óptima para resolver esta problema.

Estuve haciendo pruebas colocando a mis antecesores `display: initial` y funciona perfectamente, sin embargo que pasa cuando se tiene un `display: flex` todo se rompe.

He creado un enlace a codesandbox para su análisis y como se puede solucionar esto fácilmente (si es posible).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="app-content">
        <div class="another-container">
          <div class="card-sticky">
            Sticky card
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<style>
  .container {
    height: 200vh;
  }
  .card-sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Hola amigo, podrías añadir un [example]? Revisa [ask] pues el enlace externo podría romperse y ser inservible a futuro

Comment: a que te refieres con que todo se rompe? en el link de tu ejemplo funciona bien. en que elemento estas poniendo `display:flex`? Como sugerencia es mejor poner el el codigo aqui y adjuntar el link de tu ejemplo.

Comment: Hola, llevas algo de tiempo en el sitio, veo que no has leído el documento [ask], te sugerimos leerlo, muy importante lo que se indica para los enlaces, saludos.

Comment: No se si será la solución final pero podrías darle una mirada a esto 
 https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Veamos lo que es un elemento con [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position#tipos_de_posicionamiento):

> El elemento es posicionado de acuerdo al flujo normal del documento, y luego es desplazado con relación a su ancestro que se desplace más cercano y su bloque contenedor (ancestro en nivel de bloque más cercano) incluyendo elementos relacionados a tablas, basados en los valores de top, right, bottom, y left. El desplazamiento no afecta la posición de ningún otro elemento.

Ahora veamos una imagen con lo que está sucediendo con el elemento padre (`another-container`) y el elemento hijo (`card-sticky`):

[image: Elemento padre]
[image: Elemento Hijo]

¡El elemento hijo ya ocupa todo el espacio de su padre!

Esto es debido a que `another-container` es un **elemento en bloque**, ocupa todo el `width` que puede, pero *no hemos especificado el `height`*, por lo que ocupará lo que ocupe su elemento hijo, así que el hijo no se puede mover dentro de su contenedor.

¿Cómo soluciono esto?

Añadiendo un `height` al elemento padre, para que su hijo puede desplazarse dentro de él:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="app-content">
        <div class="another-container">
          <div class="card-sticky">
            Sticky card
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<style>
  .container{
    height: 200vh;
  }
  
  /*código nuevo*/
  .another-container{
    height:100vh;
  /*Ahora card-sticky tendrá espacio para moverse :)*/
  /*si quieres que se desplaze por toda la pantalla, le pones
  el height del ancestro que ya lo tiene definido, en este caso .container*/
  }
  /*código nuevo*/
  
  .card-sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Al llegar al final del `height` (100vh) se deja de mover el elemento hijo, pues ya alcanzó el final de su elemento padre. Al principio de todo, el final del padre era el mismo final del hijo, pero al hacer al *elemento padre más alto que el elemento hijo*, este ya pudo desplazarse libremente dentro de su ancestro.

Es decir, **tener múltiples contenedores no es la causa**, sino el hecho de no declarar un height mayor al del contenido (o `height`) que ocupe el hijo, lo que hace que no pueda desplazarse dentro del padre